# Increase by 2 values instead of 1 when the plus button is pressed in Javascipts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am working on increasing and decreasing quantity when the user buys a product. So, when the quantity over the quantity in stock of that product its denied user to increasing more and back to previous value [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwLXT.png). I am using JavaScript to do that:
The code html

```
                <div class="product-options">
                    <label>
                        Quantity In Stock
                        <span class="input">@Model.QtyinStock</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="add-to-cart">
                    <div class="qty-label">
                        Qty
                        <div class="input-number">
                            <input type="number" id="quantityInput" value="1"> 
                            <span class="qty-up">+</span>
                            <span class="qty-down">-</span>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
```

Here the javascript :

```
    $('.qty-up').click(function () {

        var currentValue = parseInt($("#quantityInput").val());
        var qtyInStock = parseInt($(".product-options .input").text());

        if (currentValue <= qtyInStock) {
            currentValue = currentValue + 1;
            $('#quantityInput').val(currentValue);
        } 
        else {
            var newValue = currentValue - 1;
            $('#quantityInput').val(newValue);
            alert("Quantity exceeds quantity in stock!");
        }
    });

    $('.qty-down').click(function () {

        var currentValue = parseInt($("#quantityInput").val());
        var newValue = currentValue--;
        $('#quantityInput').val(newValue);
    });
```

The problem is when I click plus button Its increase two values instead of one. Also, example quantity in stock is 3 and I increasing quantity I want to buy to 3, it's not allowed, but when I am decreasing quantity to 2 and click the plus button its increasing to 4 (this case its allowed). I have no idea where the problem is it. Does anyone know what is the problem? I will appreciate any intrusions. Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that you have your script loaded two times

Comment: I guess it is adding 2 instead of 1 because maybe you are running the js code twice (e.g. you are loading the js file twice). And for incrementing it to 4, the reason is that you are checking the `currentValue` like so `currentValue <= qtyInStock` which would increase the value even if it is already to the maximum value. You can use `<` instead of `<=` and remove the `else` block. that's unnecessary.

Comment: additionally, the `VARIABLE--` and `VARIABLE++` operators add the value in the next line. so `var newValue = prevValue--` won't work. you can use `--VARIABLE` operator which returns the new value too `var newValue = --prevValue` but this would be enough: `$('#quantityInput').val(currentValue - 1);`

Comment: As posted this does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: you're using a css class there which is usually not guaranteed to be unique.  Not sure if that's the problem here, but you should be using an id attribute instead (and, of course, it should be unique for this element).   Ex:  <span id="unique-item-qty-up">+</span>Then use $('#unique-item-qty-up').click(function () {  ...  }  You might also consider using the browser's built in number input... <input type="number">

Comment: After testing the code you posted, if the problem you described has not been reproduced, you can clear the browser data (cache, cookie) or create a small example to testing.